# how to show multiple rows per page using PrimeNG carousel?

Tags: angular, carousel, primeng

I am trying to create 2 rows per page in a PrimeNG Carousel.
The problem is that it currently shows all the items on 1 row.

I calculate the width and height of each item per row dynamically.

For example, if i have 13 items and the [numvisible] = 8, it should show 4 items per row with a total of 2 rows. When the user presses next page, it should show the remaining 5. 4 on the first row and 1 on the second.

I have put a StackBlitz together to show you what i have: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bvnjv8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fproject.component.ts)